# ldapsearch with mTLS (and selective curves)

Tags: ssl, ldap, openldap

I have to request a LDAP-server.
It is strictly mutual-TLS secured.

If I try TLS with openssl it works.
But I have to provide -cert, -key and -curves to openssl s_client to make it work.

Without setting cuves explicitely it would fail.

Is there a way I can provide ldapsearch these parameters?
cert and key I found, but I am not sure about the curves.

I am running a Debian 12 with ldap-utils 2.5 and OpenSSL 3.

Comment: Edit the question and add the exact `ldapsearch` commands that you used including what  you are expecting to happen and works and what doesn't work.